# Get Physical Disk space by sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a webserver and a database server, not the same machine.
I can get all the database sizes etc etc but would like to know the physical disk space used and available on the mysql server. i have no rights on the db sever, so can't use any command lines. Need to be by connecting to the database and then asking...

Is this possible? I think its not, but just hoping if anyone has a better way.

Comment: not to my knowledge.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking, but I was hoping someone knows more... or maybe has a creative solution...

Comment: maybe you'll luck out.  See what's in `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`

Comment: just had a look, but nothing about disk space... :(

Comment: maybe UDF can do something about it? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html